# How do I keep a UDP server listening in Python 3 without the WHILE loop locking up the program?

Tags: python, sockets, while-loop, server, udp

Every UDP server example I can find uses a while True loop to listen for incoming data. I'm attempting to use a single UDP socket server as part a kivy window that's also doing other things. As soon as I implement the server's while True loop everything locks up, as I guess I would expect it to do.

How do I listen on a UDP port and also have the rest of the program continue functioning?

I've tried moving the UDP server handling to another (udp_server.py) file and then importing the function, but since I'm importing the while loop nothing changes.

I've also tried assigning the received data to a variable inside udp_server.py and then just importing that variable, with udp_server.py already running separately, but even that is locking up my main program.

I'm 99.99% sure it's just some basic thing that I should already know, but I'm new to Python. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sounds like you need to look at threading or multiprocessing

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Chris!!!!!!

I'm sure I'm understating the complexity of threading, but it works great now and the only thing I had to add was:

```
def thread_function():
    from udp_server import amx_rx
    # do stuff with amx_rx...

# class TouchPanel stuff...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, daemon=True)
    x.start()
    try:
        TouchPanel().run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        raise
```

Now I have a running program with a UDP socket listening in the background! Thank you!!!

Comment: note that multithreaded code is very difficult to reason about, specifically you need to be very careful about any shared mutable state.  https://deadlockempire.github.io/ makes a nice game out of the issues

Comment: Thanks Sam. I think I might have lucked out since it's sole function is to pass in external strings. I'll definitely check out your link though because I want a better understanding going forward.